# Recommendation - Creating a new dataframe with conditions

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, recommendation-engine

I've been studying Spark for a while but today I got stuck, I'm working in a Recommendation model using Audioscrobbler Dataset.

I have my model based in ALS and the following definition for make the recommendations:

```scala
def makeRecommendations(model: ALSModel, userID: Int,howMany: Int): DataFrame = {
  val toRecommend = model.itemFactors.select($"id".as("artist")).withColumn("user", lit(userID))
     model.transform(toRecommend).
        select("artist", "prediction", "user").
        orderBy($"prediction".desc).
        limit(howMany)
}
```

It's generating the expected output, but now I would like to create a new list of DataFrames using Predictions DF and User Data DF.

[DataFrame Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVdGw.png)

New list of DF consisting of the Predicted value from "Predictions DF" and "Listened" that will be 0 if the user didn't listened the artist or 1 if the user listened, something like this:

[Expected DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq0hq.png)

I tried the following solution:

```scala
val recommendationsSeq = someUsers.map { userID =>
     //Gets the artists from user in testData
   val artistsOfUser = testData.where($"user".===(userID)).select("artist").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList
     // Recommendations for each user
   val recoms        = makeRecommendations(model, userID, numRecom)
     //Insert a column listened with 1 if the artist in the test set for the user and 0 otherwise
   val recomOutput   = recoms.withColumn("listened", when($"artist".isin(artistsOfUser: _*), 1.0).otherwise(0.0)).drop("artist")
     (recomOutput)
}.toSeq
```

But its very time consuming when the recommendation has more than 30 users. I believe there's a better way to do it,

Could someone give some idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can try joining dataframes then goupby and count:

```
scala> val df1 = Seq((1205,0.9873411,1000019)).toDF("artist","prediction","user")
scala> df1.show()
+------+----------+-------+
|artist|prediction|   user|
+------+----------+-------+
|  1205| 0.9873411|1000019|
+------+----------+-------+

scala> val df2 = Seq((1000019,1205,40)).toDF("user","artist","playcount")
scala> df2.show()
+-------+------+---------+
|   user|artist|playcount|
+-------+------+---------+
|1000019|  1205|       40|
+-------+------+---------+

scala> df1.join(df2,Seq("artist","user")).groupBy('prediction).count().show()
+----------+-----+
|prediction|count|
+----------+-----+
| 0.9873411|    1|
+----------+-----+
```